# Creating a string array of insert queries in Postgres stored procedure and executing them

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures, stored-functions

I have a requirement to construct a string array of all the insert queries with dynamic values being iterated over a cursor.

The procedure looks like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_data()
 RETURNS void AS $$
DECLARE
    interval_time INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
    rec_old   RECORD;
    rec_new   RECORD;
    rec_start RECORD;
    v_filename VARCHAR(50);
    querystring TEXT[];

    cursor_file CURSOR FOR
        select distinct(filename) from mytable.tableA;
    cursor_data CURSOR FOR
            select * from mytable.tableA where filename = v_filename order by mindatetime, maxdatetime;
BEGIN
    --open the file cursor
    OPEN cursor_file;
        LOOP
        FETCH cursor_file into v_filename;
        EXIT WHEN NOT FOUND;

            -- Open the second cursor
               OPEN cursor_data;
               FETCH cursor_data INTO rec_old;
               rec_start = rec_old;
               LOOP
                -- fetch each record
                  FETCH cursor_data INTO rec_new;
                      interval_time :=   extract(epoch from rec_new.mindatetime) * 1000 - extract(epoch from rec_old.maxdatetime) * 1000;
                      IF interval_time = 1  THEN
                        -- swap the new and old rec


                        querystring='{insert into mytable.tableA values ('rec_new.fileid,rec_new.systemuid,rec_new.filename,rec_new.mindatetime,rec_new.maxdatetime')}';
                        raise notice 'query is %', querystring;
                        rec_old = rec_new;
                      ELSE
                        -- insert new records to other table
                        RAISE NOTICE 'Values to insert: %, % ', rec_start.mindatetime, rec_old.maxdatetime;


                      END IF;
                      -- exit when no more row to fetch
                      EXIT WHEN NOT FOUND;
               END LOOP;

               -- Close the cursor
               CLOSE cursor_data;

        END LOOP;
    CLOSE cursor_file;
END; $$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I need the string array to be like:

```
{insert into mytable.tableA values ('123','dummyfilenameA','2019-04-21 03:06:26.0','2019-04-28 03:06:26.0'),
insert into mytable.tableA values ('456','dummyfilenameB','2019-05-21 03:06:26.0','2019-05-28 03:06:26.0')}
```

and so on. The array should use the records data to construct the query.
Finally, I want to execute this query string. Is there a way to do this? I can't update the table while iterating over the cursors as its impacting the data already present.

Comment: You certainly could create an array and execute each string, but I don't see why you need to do this.  In fact, I don't see any need for this function at all.  Why not just do all of this in regular SQL?  It would be much faster.

Comment: @Jeremy I have not mentioned the entire business logic for the function intentionally. On a high level its actually a cron job to insert and delete redundant data from a table based on certain scenarios

Comment: Okay, but unless the columns or table names are determined programmatically, you wouldn't need a function like this.  A single SQL statement could do both the inserts and deletes and you wouldn't have to worry about modifying the table while iterating.

Comment: @Jeremy At the moment I need the way for adding the queries and executing them. Would be great if you could help me with that

Answer (score 0):

if you use the function array_append(anyarray, anyelement) to add elements to the array querystring?

```
querystring:=array_append(querystring,'insert...');
```

Comment: I am getting error while using this ERROR:  function array_append(character varying[], unknown, character varying) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT array_append(querystring,'into...

Comment: the function array_append(anyarray, anyelement) only have two parameters for example: 
    
    select array_append(ARRAY[1,2], 3);

Comment: your are doing something wrong, you can check the doc about this function please check : https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/functions-array.html